# Recaptcha (external script) inside an angular partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

Please see the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j7KE6y?p=preview)

There are two blocks of recaptcha codes, one inside the partial `partial_list.html` and another in index.html. The one inside partial is not displayed, I assume may be because angular prevents loading external script. How can I make it work inside partial?

### Edit

As the comment , please see the code below.

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="FriendCtrl">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>in index.html</h2>
<form name="editForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveFriend()">
  <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfRgOMSAAAAAPRKoWemiQCZdhWBy2xgfWsZ_xUe">
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfRgOMSAAAAAPRKoWemiQCZdhWBy2xgfWsZ_xUe"
                    height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
            </textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                   value="manual_challenge">
        </noscript>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/edit/:friendId', {
        templateUrl: 'partial_edit.html',
        controller: FriendEditCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partial_list.html',
        controller: FriendListCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list' });
}]);
```

### partial_list.html

```
<h2>In partial</h2>

<form name="editForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveFriend()">
  <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfRgOMSAAAAAPRKoWemiQCZdhWBy2xgfWsZ_xUe">
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfRgOMSAAAAAPRKoWemiQCZdhWBy2xgfWsZ_xUe"
                    height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
            </textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                   value="manual_challenge">
        </noscript>
</form>
```

### controller.js

```
function FriendCtrl($scope) {
}

function FriendListCtrl($scope) {
}

function FriendEditCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

}
```

Comment: Please post some code in your actual question. -1

Comment: Not sure but my guess is you'll have better luck writing a directive that handles running the appropriate methods on the Recaptcha object https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: @Doorknob Please see the code inlined.

Comment: You could use vcRecaptcha from http://ngmodules.org/

Comment: You should really take advantage of directives for this.  I currently use [angular-re-captcha](https://github.com/mllrsohn/angular-re-captcha) directive that uses  its own provider that implements the recaptcha API in Angular language.  You can read about it here: [Embeding reCAPTCHA in Angular](http://brilliantbritz.com/embedding-recaptcha-in-an-angularnode-application/) where I go through this in detail